# Bar plot separated by a variable and colored by another variable

Tags: r, ggplot2, graph, bar-chart

I've spent an astonishing 4 hours googling and finding not-quite the same answers to do something that should take me 30 seconds.

Here's my data:

```
DFj <- read.table(text="Intervention Timepoint  Proportion
             0    baseline  .35
             0    final     .24
             1    baseline  .25
             1    final     .43", header=TRUE)
```

I want a bar plot of 4 bars. There should be two categories, i.e. "baseline" and "final" time points. Baseline should have two bars, control (red) and intervention (blue) which are side by side. Then I want a bit of distance before we have the same two bars with the same colors but with the "final" data. This should be insanely easy but absolutely nothing I google can help me. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you are looking for?

```
library(tidyverse)
DFj <- read.table(text="Intervention Timepoint  Proportion
             0    baseline  .35
             0    final     .24
             1    baseline  .25
             1    final     .43", header=TRUE)

DFj %>% 
  ggplot(aes(Timepoint, Proportion, fill = Intervention %>% as.factor())) +
  geom_col(position = 'dodge') + 
  scale_fill_manual(values = c('red', 'blue'))
```